# What is Far Cry's actual configuration file?

Tags: pc, far-cry

There are at least three configuration files in the game folder, two `system.cfg` files and `default_system.cfg`. Which one is actually used by the game?
`game.cfg` in the respective language folder appears to only store keybinds, which can be modified in the game anyway.

Far Cry suffers from severe texture pop-in and delayed texture loading —  draw distance can be increased to a certain degree by raising `e_vegetation_sprites_distance_ratio` value. There are some other settings such as motion blur which can't be disabled or modified in-game.